# ASP.net session alternative

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, session-variables, session-state

I have a webform that is a survey for users to fill using a sequence of questions.
I am storing the sequence reached by the user in session variable.

The problem with this implementation is that:
Suppose the user is at session 3 and press back, he will get the answers of session 2, which he wish to alter. If he now press next, he will be informed that not all questions of session 3 are filled.

Is there an alternative to Session variable that will allow me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the step number as a hidden field on the form so that it is submitted along with the form.  In this way you can respond to the relevant step even if the user uses the back button.